# How to insert <img> element into <a> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm trying to insert an image inside of a hyperlink tag.

Current markup:

```
<div class="Example">
  <a href="http://www.Example.com">
    <img src="http://www.Example.com/Sloth.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

I want to insert

```
<img class="example" src="http://www.Example.com/JellyFish.jpg">
```

So the markup is as follows:

```
<div class="Example">
  <a href="http://www.Example.com">
    <img src="http://www.Example.com/Sloth.jpg">
    <img class="example" src="http://www.Example.com/JellyFish.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

**Question**

How can I do this via Javascript or JQuery?

Comment: Dom operations: find the img tag, `.append()` your new image after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append the image a solution could be:

```
$('.Example a').append($('<img>', {class: 'example', src: 'http://www.Example.com/JellyFish.jpg'}));
```

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.Example a').append($('<img>',
                           {class: 'example', src: 'http://www.Example.com/JellyFish.jpg'}));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="Example">
    <a href="http://www.Example.com">
        <img src="http://www.Example.com/Sloth.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery `append()`...

```
$("a").append('<img class="example" src="http://www.Example.com/JellyFish.jpg">');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `insertAfter` :

```
$('<img class="example" src="http://www.Example.com/JellyFish.jpg">').insertAfter('.Example img');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('<img class="example" src="http://www.Example.com/JellyFish.jpg">').insertAfter('.Example img');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Example">
  <a href="http://www.Example.com">
    <img src="http://www.Example.com/Sloth.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .append() to insert the element into the `<a>`. Note that I have used the containing `.Example` as part of the selector to ensure specificity.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.Example a').append('<img class="example" src="http://www.Example.com/JellyFish.jpg">')
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Example">
<a href="http://www.Example.com">
     <img src="http://www.Example.com/Sloth.jpg">
</a>
</div>
```